# How to install Hive without HDFS on windows 10

Tags: hadoop, hive, windows-10

I want to install hive in standalone mode on windows 10. I want o use my local system for metastore storage instead of HDFS. what changes should be done in hive-site.xml file to start HIVE in command prompt.

Comment: The defaults do use your local system. What issues are you having running it?

Comment: command prompt is not recognizing hive commands. also what all settings to change in hive-site.xml file so that it uses local metastore and connect it through beeline.

Comment: Again, the defaults should all be fine. What do you mean "not recognized?" what's the actual error and command you're running?

Comment: First I want to clarify if I need to install hadoop environment on my system to run hive cli

Comment: The metastore itself uses a local Derby database. You shouldn't need Hadoop to start the metastore. You don't need Hadoop installed to use beeline, either

Comment: I have downloaded hive tar file and unzipped it. Then I have also set environment variables. Also I have made a default warehouse directory in my local system and changed the below property in xml file :  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
    <value>C:\Installations\Hive\warehouse</value>
    <description>location of default database for the warehouse</description>
  </property> Can you give me a sample hive-site.xml file to run hive in standalone mode.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include formatted code blocks

Comment: Also when I write beeline command in cmd why it connects to spark-shell and it gives below output  => Beeline version 1.2.1.spark2 by Apache Hive

Comment: It's built and maintained within the Spark project. It's not connecting to anything unless you do `beeline -u address:port`

Comment: C:\Users\sachin>beeline -u !connect jdbc:hive2://localmode:9083
scan complete in 1ms
2019-10-08 13:22:42 ERROR ClassNameCompleter:225 - Fail to parse the class name from the Jar file due to the exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException: minlog-1.2.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
2019-10-08 13:22:42 ERROR ClassNameCompleter:225 - Fail to parse the class name from the Jar file due to the exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException: objenesis-1.2.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)

Comment: 2019-10-08 13:22:42 ERROR ClassNameCompleter:225 - Fail to parse the class name from the Jar file due to the exception:java.io.FileNotFoundException: reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
scan complete in 2458ms
No known driver to handle "hive2://localmode:9083"
Beeline version 1.2.1.spark2 by Apache Hive
beeline>

Answer (score 0):

The hive Metadata is just stored in a relational DB, this is not on Hdfs. There is a default which you can configure to point elsewhere. The actual hive data needs to rest on Hdfs as far as I know.